# MVC unobtrusive validation queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using unobtrusive validation in MVC for a search application, and on the whole it works well, except for 2 things that I can't find any answers for. I've used it before, and I don't remember these being an issue, so it could just be my setup in this application.

The first issue is that it immediately tells me that the search query input is invalid, or at least shows the error message for it, despite it being valid to begin with. It has some text added to it via the model, so it has a value when the page loads, therefore I can't understand why the unobtrusive validation fails it and shows the error message it when it loads.

The second issue is that it doesn't see a whitespace (" ") string as an error despite being 'required' and having 'AllowEmptyStrings' set to false, along with a 'ConvertEmptyStringToNull' DisplayFormat. I thought this would catch the whitespace, but it isn't doing.

I've overcome both these issues, the first by calling the validation manually in Document.Ready, which proves that the input is indeed valid. And the second by adding a manual check before the form is submitted. Both of these are convoluted, especially the first issue, I'd like to know why it doesn't work as expected, and avoid this issue in the future

The relevant parts of the code are below:

The SearchVM view model with the searchTerm property and the annotations.

```
public class SearchVM : PageDetails
{               
    public string SpellingSuggestion { get; set; }
    public List<Result> SearchResults { get; set; }
    public int ResultsCount { get; set; }

    private string searchTerm = "";
    [Display(Name = "Search the website")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a search term", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string SearchTerm { get
        {
            return searchTerm;
        }
        set {
            //Strip out bad characters from the search term
            if (value != null) { 
                searchTerm = Regex.Replace(value, @"[‘’#!@\$%]", "");
            } else
            {
                searchTerm = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Index view where the query is displayed:

```
@model SearchVM
@{
    Model.Title = "Search the website";
    Model.Description = "Search the website.";
    Model.Keywords = ", website, search, google, find, websearch";
    Model.Class = "search";
}
<main class="search">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Results", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results", OnComplete= "moreInfoDropDown(), spellingSuggestion()" }))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchTerm)
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTerm, new { maxlength = 30, autocomplete = "off" })
        </div>
        <input type="image" src="~/Images/search/icon.png" alt="Search" tabindex="3" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchTerm)
    } 
    <div id="results">
        @if (Model.SearchResults != null)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_ResultsIntro", Model)
        }
    </div>
</main>
```

And the controller that calls the view (in this scenario, the query is null, so it always calls the Index with the searchTerm set to "Search the website"):

```
// GET: Search
public ActionResult Index(SearchVM searchVM, string query)
{
    // If there is a query added to the URL, use it
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query)) {
        searchVM.SearchTerm = query;
    }
    // Re-load the typical index with no results if the search term is empty
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchVM.SearchTerm))
        {    return View(new SearchVM() { SearchTerm = "Search the website" });
    }
    // Return the index with the queried result (if applicable)
    return View(GSA.Query(searchVM.SearchTerm, 0));
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give. I don't think any other parts of the code are relevant, but please let me know if you need to see more, and I will add it to the question.

Comment: Can you check traffic and make sure there is no client side code to submit your form somewhere in an event that may be unexpectedly firing?

Comment: That would mean the form was submitting immediately upon the page loading, and that doesn't seem to be the case. I also have some custom validation upon submitting for the second issue (so it doesn't submit a white space search), and that doesn't fire when the page loads, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Not a lot of your code is making sense. First you get the error message because you GET method has a parameter for you model, so if you do not call it by initially passing a parameter for `SearchTerm`, the a `ModelState` error is added (setting the value of `SearchTerm` after its invalid does not remove the error). Secondly that property should be a simple `{ get; set; }` and you apply a `[RegularExpression]` attribute to it if you want it to follow a pattern. Your `<form>` is making a POST but you have not shown a POST method. And nowhere do you ever appear to be sending a value for `query`

Comment: I'll try to explain the code. The query part is an optional URL parameter,  so if it's there, it's set as the search term, otherwise it's left blank. I wanted the searchTerm to be corrected without user intervention, but adding a regexp to the model would just mean they'd have to correct it themselves. The post part isn't important, as it's just when it first loads that it shouldn't show the error. I think that you may have a point about the ModelState error though, so I'll look into that. Shouldn't the Model show no errors to begin with though (to give the user chance to put something in)?

Comment: Yes, typically the view would show no errors, but in your case you have added errors yourself because your GET method contains a parameter for your model (and because the url does not include `&SearchTerm=someValue` that property is null and therefore invalid). Just remove that parameter (and initialize a new instance of `SearchVM` in the method)

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Muecke said in his comment, I was incorrectly passing the searchVM model to the controller, and therefore it was already invalid before being passed to the view. Removing that parameter, and instead initialising a new instance of the model solved the issue.

Thanks to Stephen for pointing this out.